# Modifying the routing asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP MVC application, I need to show the URL path like this:

> domain.com/viewName

I have the route config in the follow way:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allfiles}", new { allfiles = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)" });            

        routes.MapRoute(
           "Theme",
           "theme/{theme}/{page}",
           new { controller = "Theme", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new[] { "Tenant.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "ThemeSlider",
           "theme/slider/{id}",
           new { controller = "Theme", action = "Slider" },
           new[] { "Tenant.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Tenant.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default_tenant",
            "{page}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Tenant.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
```

But it does not works, I have to specify the page parameter in the follow way: **domain.com/?page=viewName**. How should be the route config that leaves the follow routes:

domain.com.co/controller/action/
domain.com.co/view

Any sugestion ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Samich for the edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to get rid of the controller? This sort of thing will work, but beware of conflicts between routes in different controllers:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeRoute",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
    constraints: new { homeControllerConstraint = new HomeControllerConstraint() }
);
```

Now every action in the home controller maps to Domain.com/Action instead of Domain.com/Home/Action.

Here is some reflective code to efficiently work out whether a route is in the home controller, for instance.

```
internal class HomeControllerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly Lazy<HashSet<string>> homeMethods = new Lazy<HashSet<string>>(CreateHomeMethods);

    private static HashSet<string> CreateHomeMethods()
    {
        return typeof(HomeController).GetMethods().Select(e => e.Name.ToLower()).ToSet();
    }

    public static bool Exists(string name)
    {
        return homeMethods.Value.Contains(name.Trim().ToLower());
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return homeMethods.Value.Contains(values["action"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam Brown, it was helpfully